# How do I convert arrays into functions in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I turn these arrays into functions? I can't find anything online on how to do it.

```
$stateArray = array(
    "ct"=>"Connecticut",
    "ma"=>"Massachusetts",
    "nj"=>"New Jersey",
    "ny"=>"New York",
    "ri"=>"Rhode Island");

$destinationArray = array(
    "easterncaribbean"=>"Eastern Caribbean",
    "southerncaribbean"=>"Southern Caribbean",
    "westerncaribbean"=>"Western Caribbean",
    "bermuda"=>"Bermuda",
    "bahamas"=>"Bahamas");
```

Comment: You should at least rephrase this so that your post wont sound so homework*ish*

Comment: Your "homework directions" have nothing to do with converting arrays into functions! If you read them again, it's asking you to create two functions to "provide" the two arrays.

Comment: He actually rephrased it. Lol

Comment: lol but for real though...

Comment: it does say convert arrays into functions

Comment: @Eddie which has made it unclear now...

Comment: Do you mean, how to call function `ct` and get returned **"Connecticut"**, if so, a function is overkill for that and you can simply access the array `$stateArray['ct']` to return **"Connecticut"**.

Comment: @ReinylNeri Hmmm No, you want to create functions that return the arrays... It's seems like a very simple question to show you know how to create a function that returns "something".

Comment: This question makes no sense as it is worded.  There is no benefit to calling a custom function, just to declare an array.  More information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function states() {
  return array(
    "ct"=>"Connecticut",
    "ma"=>"Massachusetts",
    "nj"=>"New Jersey",
    "ny"=>"New York",
    "ri"=>"Rhode Island"
  );
}

function destinations() {
  return array(
    "easterncaribbean"=>"Eastern Caribbean",
    "southerncaribbean"=>"Southern Caribbean",
    "westerncaribbean"=>"Western Caribbean",
    "bermuda"=>"Bermuda",
    "bahamas"=>"Bahamas"
  );
}

$states       = states();
$destinations = destinations();
```

Is this what you were after? Functions are just recyclable snippets of code, so make sure you remember that.

**NOTE**: Your question didn't make sense.

Comment: I must then use it to display the results on a select box for a web form

Comment: @ReinylNeri Well your question never mentioned anything about "select" boxes on a webform. But you can look up how to do that. Did you go to any of your classes?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I was able to read it through the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

To create functions which return array:

```
// function to return State array
function getStateArray() {
    $stateArray = array(
        "ct"=>"Connecticut",
        "ma"=>"Massachusetts",
        "nj"=>"New Jersey",
        "ny"=>"New York",
        "ri"=>"Rhode Island"
    );

    return $stateArray;
}


// function to return Destination array
function getDestinationArray() {
    $destinationArray = array(
        "easterncaribbean"=>"Eastern Caribbean",
        "southerncaribbean"=>"Southern Caribbean",
        "westerncaribbean"=>"Western Caribbean",
        "bermuda"=>"Bermuda",
        "bahamas"=>"Bahamas"
    );

    return $destinationArray;
}
```

You can call those function like this:

```
// call function to get State array
$state = getStateArray();

// this print "Connecticut"
echo "state ct: " . state['ct'];


// call function to get Destination array
$destination = getDestinationArray();

// this print "Eastern Caribbean"
echo "destination easterncaribbean: " . destination['easterncaribbean'];
```